# Is there something like std::any_of that will apply predicate to all elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

> The behavior of std::any_of function template is equivalent to:

```
 template<class InputIterator, class UnaryPredicate>   bool any_of
 (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred) {  
 while (first!=last) {
     if (pred(*first)) return true;
     ++first;   }   return false; }
```

So it won't apply predicate to all elements. is there some other function that return true if any of the elements return true for this predicate, but in the same time t will run the predicate for all elements from the given range?

UPD: so for why I need that - my function modify element of the container by certain rule and return true of element was modified and false otherwise. So I need to know if any of the elements was modified

Comment: If you're willing to drop the requirement for c++11 this could be done with `std::reduce`. Either way, this sounds like you're trying to stuff something into a predicate that isn't supposed to be there.

Comment: Please clarify your question. A predicate is a function that returns true/false. What do you mean by apply/run the predicate.

Comment: Sounds like a predicate is doing more job than it should. Split it into two parts, first call `std::for_each`, then call `std::any_of`.

Comment: use `std::accumulate` or `std::count_if`

Answer (score 1):

> is there some other function that return true if any of the elements return true for this predicate, but in the same time t will run the predicate for all elements from the given range?
>
> my function modify element of the container

There is no function in `std` that will do that. Only `std::for_each`(`_n`) allows modification of elements by its callable parameter.

You can write a wrapper for that

```
template <typename MutableForwardIter, typename MutatingPredicate>
bool my_any_of(MutableForwardIter first, MutableForwardIter last, MutatingPredicate pred) {
    bool any = false;
    std::for_each(first, last, [&any, pred](auto & val){ any |= pred(val); });
    return any;
}
```